# Is this sentence grammatically correct / does it make any sense?

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence right?

**"I hadn't seen anything like this before, nor did I anticipate I ever will."**

I feel like it doesn't sound right it sounds weird (I'm not a native so I could be wrong) what do you think? Shouldn't it be "nor did I anticipate I ever would"?

Comment: why do you think it is or isn't? Where did this sentence come from?

Comment: Following up on the comment from @Esther, without more info this is a proofreading request and thus off-topic.

Comment: @Esther from a YouTube video, I was watching a documentary and the doctor said this sentence. He actually said: "I had not seen anything like this before NOR DO I ANTICIPATED I EVER WILL." but I feel like it doesn't sound right it sounds weird (I'm not a native so I could be wrong) what do you think? Shouldn't it be "nor did I anticipate I ever would "? I can provide the link of the video if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

> I hadn't seen anything like this before, nor did I anticipate I ever **would.**

or

> I hadn't seen anything like this before, nor **do** I anticipate I ever **will**.